# paxos algorithm - how does the propose stage work?

Tags: distributed-computing, distributed-system, paxos

I am looking at the pseudocode for the PROPOSE stage of the paxos algorithm: [https://www.cs.rutgers.edu/~pxk/417/notes/paxos.html](https://www.cs.rutgers.edu/%7Epxk/417/notes/paxos.html)

```
did I receive PROMISE responses from a majority of acceptors?
if yes
    do any responses contain accepted values (from other proposals)?
    if yes
        val = accepted_VALUE    // value from PROMISE message with the highest accepted ID
    if no
        val = VALUE     // we can use our proposed value
    send PROPOSE(ID, val) to at least a majority of acceptors
```

If one of the peers has previously accepted a value (`accepted_VALUE`), what happens to the value that the proposer is trying to propose (`VALUE`)?

As I understand it looking at the pseudocode, it gets discarded? That seems like a loss of information...

Answer (score 1):

The proposer *does* discard its value when an acceptor responds with a value.

I think of it like this: Paxos is a *cooperation* protocol, much like a wait-free-lock-free algorithm. The proposer's job is **not** to ensure its value is chosen, but to help the process along. When a proposer sees that it was beat out by another proposer, it helps to replicate that other proposers.

In a similar vein, you can think of it as the proposer is continuing the work of a prior, potentially dead proposer.

You can see this more clearly in the simpler, non-consensus Attiya/Bar-Noy/Dolev (ABD) protocol. Even when *reading* in ABD the "proposer" re-writes the value to the peers to ensure the value is distributed across the system.

---

ABD: "Sharing memory robustly in message-passing systems", H. Attiya, A. Bar-Noy, and D. Dolev, 1995

Comment: Thanks for explaining. I'm still a bit confused though. If one were building kv store on top of paxos, how would you make sure that all keys are correctly accounted for? How do you deal with unchosen values?

Comment: @nz_21 Think of each Paxos instance as choosing a single entry in a *write ahead log* (WAL) and **NOT** as what stores the values in the database. The *value* chosen in each paxos instance would be a blob representing a complete transaction, even with multiple rows being changed. So paxos's chosen value would be something like `SET x=1, y=2 where id=123; SET x=4, y=3 where id=456;`